# Cloud based solution for hosting training videos that integrates with our Active Directory

Tags: video, cloud-service, active-directory

The use case is several hundred users who need access to video based training produced and uploaded by their technical support team. Users will need to access these videos via the Internet, but should be able to use their standard AD credentials to login. Content should be easy to find for the end user. The system does not need to be a training management system. It simply needs to be a secure place to stream these videos from an easy to use interface.

It should have an integrated CMS to allow the content producers to easily upload, categorize, and maintain the videos.

Comment: Now in 2020 there is Microsoft Teams maybe.